Git Submodules: Double Submodules
I have three repositories (names are [1], [2] and [3]), and then I make 2 submodules, [1] is [2] parent repository, [2] is [3] parent repository, when I look them on BitBucket, it achieved my goal, I can see the submodules between [1], [2] and [2], [3].
Now I use git clone --recurse-submodules {url} to clone [1] repository, I can get repository [1] and submodules [2], and I use git clone --recurse-submodules {url} to clone [2] repository, I can get repository [2] and submodules [3].
But when I use git clone --recurse-submodules {url} to clone [1] repository why can't I see submodules [3] in submodules [2]? 
tree example:
| project [1]
   //(submodules)
  | Project [2]
     //(submodules)
    | Project [3]


Must work. That is, git clone --recurse-submodules repo1 must clone both repo2 and repo3. Any errors during clone? Can you provide a [mcve], i.e. 3 public repositories for us to clone?

It was cloned successfully and no error message was displayed. I was wondering if there are other commands that can directly complete my needs？？？
